# How get access to classes from submodules?

Tags: gradle

My project has 3 modules.
**app, module_1, module_2.**

settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':module_1'
include ':module_2'
```

Module "app" is a main module. In this module I have a class MyClass.
And it's working fine.

But from the submodules (module_1, module_2) I can't get access to this class.

What can I do to access MyClass from submodules?

In the main module I have many useful utility classes.
But the submodules do not have access to all of this classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the respective build.gradle, you need

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':app') 
}
```

> main module I has many useful util classes

You should consider moving your util classes to their own module

Comment: If I add to module_1 in build.gradle: compile project(':app') ---> I get error: Error:Circular reference between projects: :app -> :module_1-> :app

Comment: Well, that is how you would include the classes into the sub-module. Like I said, you should extract out the "minimal" util classes, then figure out the best structure of dependencies to avoid circles